# Swift - Add two string numbers

Tags: swift

Basically the user types in their number and clicks a button. It then adds it on top of the value of a label. However the following code adds it on to the end of the string and doesn't physically add the strings

```
let currentStamps = Int(labelStamps.text!)
let stamps = Int(textFieldStamps.text!)
labelStamps.text = stamps! + currentStamps!
```

Help please

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to store your values in ui elements. You should store your "stamps" value as integer in model layer, perform calculations with stored ints and update UI from those recalculated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if let currentStamps = Int(labelStamps.text!), let stamps = Int(textFieldStamps.text!) {
        labelStamps.text = "\(stamps + currentStamps)"
    }
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much you've just helped me so much btw I'm only twelve so you've really helped me thanks